How do I get interface similar to moto G first generation or iPhone 6
I have a Samsung Galaxy S22. How do I get an interface similar to moto G first generation or iPhone 6?
Just all apps on the home screen or screens are obtained by scrolling right. Disable ALL other things like scrolling down for the list of apps, unexpected side menus, etc.

The way how Android presents the apps depends on the installed Launcher. Therefore to me your actual question is "Which launcher app shows all apps on the the start screen(s) just like an iPhone does"? Note that asking for app recommendations is off-topic here, use our sister site softwarerecs.stackexchange.com instead.

Posted to SoftwareRecs.SE: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/91348/520

Based on the question body, I'm closing this question as a dupe to the linked question about homescreen only. If you want overall user interface of iOS, then I'm afraid the customization is too broad unless you can specify what you really want.
